# Login not working in Silex with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, silex

I'm developing a project with a small client area with the Silex framework. I want to store the session in database using the `SessionServiceProvider` and `PdoSessionHandler` but when I try to login with a test account the session is written in the database but the login is not done correctly and I get the login page in a loop. Also I'm getting the following error in the error log

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"
```

The sessions table looks like this (got it from the [Silex documentation page](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/session_storage.html)):

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    sess_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    sess_value TEXT NOT NULL,
    sess_time INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(sess_id)
);
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Did you create the table in Postgres using UTF8 storage (on table/column or whole database)?

Comment: The database is defined like this: `backoffice   | qiuandei | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself with the same error some time ago, looks like the silex documentation is incorrect for PostgreSQL, the `sess_value` field should be a `BYTEA` type field because the session data can contain characters that are not accepted in UTF-8 like the NULL character *0x00*.

Also as Silex uses the Symfony2 components for storing the session in database another field should be added, sess_lifetime that will contain the lifetime of the database session.

So the definition should be:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    sess_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    sess_value BYTEA NOT NULL,
    sess_time INTEGER NOT NULL,
    sess_lifetime INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(sess_id)
);
```

Comment: Great!! I changed the table definition and not it's working!! Thanks a lot!!